# About MethodID：0x095ea7b3

Tags: erc-20, ether, method

Everyone directs that this ID is used for
approve(address,uint256), can I create my own MethodID, but the function is the same as 0x095ea7b3.

Answer (score 1):

The method ID or as we call it `function signature` is basically a hash of the function's name and its attributes. For example, consider your approve method:

```
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {}
```

The `function signature` of this function would be a hash of `approve(address, amount)`. And since hash has the property that even a small change can change the hash, it is difficult to create another function with the same signature.

But since the signature only uses the first 4 bytes, replicating the signature can be a possibility. There has been a hack because of this issue too. So basically you can, but for that you would need a proxy contract, otherwise the contract will have 2 functions with same signature, which is not allowed.